# How to write separable (trennbare) verbs in enumeration?

Tags: sentence-structure, separable-verb

Let's assume there is a sentence with an enumeration:

> *It proposes and analyses possible scenarios…*

In a German version I would write it as:

> *Es schlägt vor und analysiert mögliche Szenarien…*

The thing I'm not sure about is, how to use here a separable (trennbare) verb.

Should I write it as in the example above, or it's better to adjust a sentence structure to be more «German»:

> *Es schlägt mögliche Szenarien vor und analysiert sie…*

**Bonus:**
What will be the rule in case there is an enumeration of multiple separable verbs with different prefixes? E.g.:

> *Er schlägt vor und schreibt auf dieses Buch.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - **Es schlägt mögliche Szenarien vor und analysiert sie …**
> - **Er schlägt dieses Buch vor und schreibt darauf**

are the word orders to go with.

---

## Reasons

> <s>Es schlägt *vor* und analysiert mögliche Szenarien …</s>
>   <s>Er schlägt vor und schreibt auf dieses Buch.</s>

aren't possible word orders if *mögliche Szenarien*/*dieses Buch* are supposed to be the object of *vorschlagen* because of two reasons:

1. In this kind of enumeration, no part of the sentence might be placed between the first verb and the conjunction: <s>*sie züchtet seit kurzem und verkauft Fisch*e</s><sup>1</sup>,
2. *Vorschlagen* is a *separable verb*, whose object would have to be placed between stem and prefix.

To fix problem (1), one could place *vor* behind the object. However, that's impossible as is would implicitly render the second verb *analysieren* **voranalysieren*.

Furthermore, even if it wasn't for reason (1), *vorschlagen* would appear to have no object because of reason (2) if the separated prefix occurs directly after the stem, making the sentence translate to: *It suggests [missing: what it suggests]. It analyzes possible scenarios.*

---

## How this kind of enumeration can be used

This implies that it is possible to enumerate verbs in front of a common object in two cases:

1. They aren't separable verbs: *Sie liest und schreibt Bücher* (example taken from your comment)
2. *Not recommended in formal language:* They are separable verbs that split off the same prefix: *Es **stellt** und **schlägt** mögliche Szenarien **vor** …* – here you have *vorstellen* and *vorschlagen* that both split off *vor*

---

<sup>1</sup> Example by *DavidVogt*, thanks for the comment

Comment: Thanks. But at the same time, is _She reads and writes books_ → _Sie liest und schreibt Bücher_ correct or not? If not, do I understand it correctly, that in German it's impossible to enumerate several verbs and only then to provide an object?

Comment: @MikeB. tanks for giving a counterexample – *Sie liest und schreibt Bücher* is indeed correct and shows that the problem is that in case of separable verbs, the prefix has to come after the object, but on the other hand that would interfere with the second verb if it hasn't the same prefix coincidentally. I'll add it in my answer

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with separable verbs *per se*: *Sie züchtet und verkauft seit kurzem Fische* is fine, but *sie züchtet seit kurzem und verkauft Fische* is not (or at least *Fische* is interpreted as object of the second verb only).

Comment: @DavidVogt However, it's the coincidence of the facts that (1) no part of the sentence can be placed between the first verb and *und* plus (2) that the prefix can neither be placed after the common object which renders it impossible to use separable verbs in this kind of enumeration (the question being "how to write separable verbs in enumeration"). I updated my answer accordingly, thanks for the annotation!

Comment: Two things I’d like to note: 1) If the subject performing the actions is already established, switching to passive voice can also solve the problem: »Es werden mögliche Szenarien vorgeschlagen und analysiert …« 2) »Es stellt und schlägt mögliche Szenarien vor«: This sounds really weird, similar to joke sentences like: »Ich heiße Heinz und Sie herzlich willkommen«. Is that just me? My brain interprets »vor« exclusively as a part of »schlägt« and then gets confused because »Szenarien stellen« doesn’t make sense.

Comment: *Es stellt und schlägt mögliche Szenarien vor* -- this I find a very questionable suggestion.

Comment: Apparently, one can argue over it (it's not a suggestion by the way—the "word order to go with" is still the foremost in the answer). In written language, of course it can be confusing if you already parsed the verb as *steIlen* instead of *vorstellen*. When spoken, however, I think it depends where you put the accent. It's possible to make a short pause after *stellt* so that the listener expects something to come in this place. Furthermore, I would emphasize *und*.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. One more point, regarding _» Es **stellt** und **schlägt** mögliche Szenarien **vor**«_, and what would be algorithm in case I have an enumeration  of **two separable** verbs with a different prefixes?

Comment: @MikeB. Basically the same as when you have a separable and an inseparable verb, by using a pronoun: *Es **schlägt** mögliche Szenarien **vor** und **leuchtet** sie **aus*** (here: *vorstellen* and *ausleuchten*).

Comment: @MikeB. I edited my answer to include your bonus question. It's *Er schlägt dieses Buch vor und schreibt darauf* – *darauf* replaces _*auf es_.

Comment: @besc *Ich heiße Heinz und Sie herzlich willkommen* is a *Zeugma*, however this is the complementary case to the question: in a Zeugma you have a common verb used in two different semantic contexts. In *Es stellt und schlägt mögliche Szenarien vor*, however, you have two different verbs with a common prefix. Omitting one of these identical split-off prefixes (*vor*), enabling the enumeration of the verbs in the way shown above, is called *Syllepse*.